# Transferring strings through a constructor. Error

Tags: c#, string, constructor

I have been working on a program for school, I am trying to transfer strings between forms in C# using a constructor. the method I am using worked previously when transferring from1 to 2 but doesn't work now transferring form2 to 3. The code is for a math quiz of ten questions. Thanks

```
 public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent(); 
    }

    public Form2(string name, string age)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        int Score;

        int QNUM; 




    }  



        private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
         {

            }

         private void label5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
         {

         }

          private void button1_Click( int answer, string name, string age, int score, int QNUM, object sender, EventArgs e)
          {   

              if (age == "Year 3")
              {
                  Random rnd = new Random();
                  int Number1 = rnd.Next(1, 51);
                  int Number2 = rnd.Next(1, 51);
                  int Answer = Number1 + Number2;
                  label4.Text = Convert.ToString(Number1 + " + " + Number2);
              }

              if( textBox1.Text == Convert.ToString(answer))
              {
                  score = score + 1;
              }
              if (textBox1.Text == Convert.ToString(answer))
              {
                  score = score + 1;
              }
                  QNUM = QNUM + 1;
                  label2.Text = Convert.ToString(QNUM);
              if ( QNUM == 1)
              {
                  button1.Text = "Next";
              }
              if (QNUM == 9)
              {
                  button1.Text = "Finish";
              }

              if (QNUM == 11)
              {
                  Form3 Name2 = new Form3 (name, score);
                  Name2.Show();
              }
         }
      }       
}
```

I also have placed code in the third form

```
    public Form3()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    public Form3(string name, string score)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        {

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have made a good start, but there are some problems with your code:

- `name` is not in the scope of the method `button1_Click`. You receive a parameter from the `Form2` constructor, but you never set it.
- `score` is an `int`, not a `string`.
- It seems you are trying to pass in parameters though the `Click` event handler. That is not possible. Use class variables instead.

Use this for your `Form2` constructor:

```
private string Name {get;set;}
private int Score {get;set;}

public Form2(string name, string age)
{
    InitializeComponent();

    this.Name = name;
    this.Score = 0;
}
```

And this for your `Form3` constructor:

```
private string Name {get;set;}
private int Score {get;set;}

public Form3(string name, int score)
{
    InitializeComponent();

    this.Name = name;
    this.Score = score;
}

public Form3() : this("defaultName", 0)
{ }
```

Then call the constructor like this:

```
Form3 Name2 = new Form3 (this.Name, this.Score);
```

Then fix your `Click` event handler:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
```